# Get Real Path of mp3 file from Uri

Tags: java, android, audio

I have picked audio file from Content Picker intent inside Fragment which `extend PreferenceFragmentCompat`

```java
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and Retrieved `Uri` from `onActivityResult`

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        audio = data.getData();
        inputfile= (FileInputStream  getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);
}
```

Where audio is declared public(Uri audio).
Now i wanted this audio file to be copied to a Directory in App Directory(`/data/data/com.example.focusit`).For this i need to get Real path of audio file from URI

```java
public String getRealPathFromUri(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
    };
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

Now to copy audio file to my directoy i used this code

```java
File audiofile = new File(audio.getPath());
String realpath = getRealPathFromUri(audio);
File file = new File("/data/data/com.example.focusit/Focusit_SOS/tt_temp.mp3");
if (!file.exists()) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Director focus it does not existed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    file.mkdirs();
}
try {
    FileUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(audiofile), new FileOutputStream(file));enter code here
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

But problem is that in function `getRealPathFromUri(Uri ContentUri)` `cursor.movetoFirst()` is returning false.Any idea how to deal with it.
Output of `audio.getpath()` is `/external/audio/media/8099`.

i tried one solution by creating Input stream directly from Uri in onActivityResult()

```
 inputfile= (FileInputStream) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

but i am getting exception

```
2020-10-28 07:41:31.333 21292-21292/com.example.focusit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.focusit, PID: 21292
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/audio/media/8099 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.focusit/com.example.focusit.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.focusit has no access to content://media/external/audio/media/8099
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4905)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4946)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.focusit has no access to content://media/external/audio/media/8099
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:705)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1702)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1518)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1202)
    at com.example.focusit.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment.onActivityResult(SettingsActivity.java:227)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8249)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4946) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) `
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing Storage access will resolve Exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.focusit has no access to content:
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not open a FileInputStream on a path you do not have.

Instead open an InputStream on the obtained uri directly.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

Comment: there is no function named getData() in Uri.I believe Uri in your comment is data.

Comment: ???? You use it yourself: `audio = data.getData();`.

Comment: after i add  `inputfile= (FileInputStream) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());`  i am getting exception

Comment: ' java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/audio/media/8099 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.focusit/com.example.focusit.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.focusit has no access to content://media/external/audio/media/8099
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4905)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4946)
        '

Comment: If you want to show code then do so in your post. In comments its unreadable as you can see. Remove those comments.

Comment: Meanwhile delete those comments.

Comment: Please post a new onActivityResult function in which you directly do the copy. It is very unclear when you do the copy now. Did you try to open the inputstream in onActivityResult already? It will work!

Comment: You changed my code. Just put my code line in onActivityResult.

Comment: Is now everything all right or should I edit my code again.

Comment: Yes edit it again as you did not do the things i asked you to do.